# What is the F# syntax for "not equal to"?

Tags: f#

In C code, it would be like this:

```
if (c != 0) { //some code ...}
```

what about in F#?

Comment: Thx for the information, sorry

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  He's not asking about "!"; he's asking how to test that a number is not equal to a particular value.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

From [MSDN's page on F# arithmetic operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469493.aspx), it looks like you want `x <> 0`.

Comment: There is also `not (x = 0)`

Answer (score 10):

I think what you're looking for is the [F# not operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370457.aspx) or the [<> operator for inequality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370488.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the other answers, you can also use pattern matching:

```
match c with
| 0 -> ()  //do nothing
| _ -> ... //do something
```

Answer (score 8):

<> is used for inequality

```
(1<>2)
```