# Why is the use of '!=' considered ambiguous but a similar use of '=' is not?

Tags: generics, f#

I was playing with some F# code using [this](http://rextester.com/runcode) online compiler (I could not find the exact F# compiler version, this will be relevant later). I realized the following two functions were very different:

```
let f x y = x = y
let g x y = x != y
```

`f` is completely generic, but to my surprise `g` was not. Calling `g 1 2` will cause a compilation error with the message:

> A generic construct requires that the type 'int' have reference semantics, but it does not, i.e. it is a struct

I went and tried this on my own machine (using F# 3.0 on mono, but I get the same result in Visual Studio 2012) and received a completely different error when I tried to define `g`:

> error FS0332: Could not resolve the ambiguity inherent in the use of the operator '( != )' at or near this program point. Consider using type annotations to resolve the ambiguity.

Why is this use of `!=` ambiguous and why is it an error? Also, why is this use of `!=` considered ambiguous but use of `=` in `f` is not? The new error is helpful in alerting me to a case where automatic generalization did not work as I had expected. However, this does seem to be a breaking change between two different versions of the F# compiler. Searches for both of these error messages turned up empty. I did not see anything in the [F# specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html) that seemed relevant. Any pointers to relevant sections would be helpful.

Comment: Linking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130181/what-is-the-f-syntax-for-not-equal-to

Comment: Terrible error message. What kind of a compiler requires Stack Overflow in order to figure out that `!=` isn't an operator in the language? Especially when `!=` is an operator in every other language that runs on the .NET VM? Isn't this supposed to be a high-level language?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that `!=` is not the name of the inequality operator in F#, `<>` is.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx

Using `<>` should be possible just the same as `=` in your example.

Comment: Now I wonder why `!=` is even allowed at all (perhaps because it could be a custom operator?). With a C# background, `!=` was natural and that online compiler let me get away with using it for so long.

Comment: @mikez A compiler can only do so much to infer intent. Not everyone coding F# comes from an algol background.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Most of my confusion comes from the fact that I have written snippets that worked as I expected with `!=` in that online compiler. I logged a suggestion with them to upgrade/fix their compiler.

Comment: I would love to see those snippets (seriously). If you could post some gists that would be great.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mzboray/7179253#file-stackoverflow_incorrectinequalityoperator-fs). It still behaves as it did when I wrote this question.

Comment: @mikez Although it works at rextester it [produces](http://rextester.com/BKJDQ93877) a warning. I've checked and invoking fsc.exe produces 'Microsoft (R) F# Compiler version 11.0.50727.1'

Comment: @ren Well that explains it. I can't believe I never noticed that Show compiler warnings option before. If it's there for ML compatibility, then the spec's section on ML compatibility constructs seems to be incomplete. There is no mention of `!=` (or `==`) in that section. Both generate ML compatibility warnings.

Answer (score 9):

The existing answer explains why the code does not behave as expected, so let me just add an explanation of what is the error message trying to say.

F# supports custom operators and you will get the same error message for any other (valid) operator symbol that you try to use in a function, for example the fish operator:

```
let fish x y = x <*>><< y
```

In this case, F# cannot define a generic function, because .NET does not have a way of specifying generic constraint saying that the type of one or the other argument support the `<*>><<` operator (in .NET language, the constraint would have to say that one of the types needs a specific static method).

This is not the case for comparison or equality (because F# has a way to represent these). But if you use something like `+` then you still won't get a generic function, but a function specialized to `int`. In that case,  you can use `inline` and write a function that is generic (requires the `+` operator):

```
let inline add x y = x + y
add 1 2
add 1.1 2.2
```

Similarly, you could define an inline function that requires any custom operator (like fish or `!=`) but you would still not be able to call it with any standard types.

Comment: +1 Great detail, thanks. Does the same apply to the [`¸.·´¯·.´¯·.¸¸.·´¯·.¸><(((º>` operator](http://1lineart.kulaone.com/art/41) ? :P

Comment: I'm afraid the set of characters allowed in custom operators is [quite limited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204.aspx), and in particular doesn't include any non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @RubenBartelink The best you can do is probably `.-^-..-^-..-^-..-^-..>><<*>` :-)

Comment: Most of my confusion stems from the fact that online compiler accepted `!=` and did what I expected with reference types. I logged a suggestion that they update/fix their F# compiler. Thanks for the explanation of the error message.

Comment: @TomasPetricek Yeah, but is it `CLSCompliant`?  :P